# Make all fields required by default, in springDoc-generated openapi specification

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, springdoc

It seems like the spring-doc generator sets all fields as optional, by default, and makes them required - when you explicitly annotate them with `@NotNull`

This is the opposite of how I work - my fields are all required until annotated with `@Nullable`.

Is is possible to fix this behaviour for my code?

Comment: Don't think there's a cleaner way of doing. You can raise a feature request for the same but I'm not sure if that'll be prioritized as this is a rare situation.

Answer (score 1):

**My answer is not a solution**, but a summary of all the problems you could encounter why trying to implement a solution. I met them all and decided, after all, to give up and use an "explicit @NotNull" strategy instead of an "explicit @Nullable" one.

I thought all these caveats could be of some interest if anybody would like to try their way.

---

First, don't rely on a SpringDoc `PropertyCustomizer`, as it's not called on each property but on each "type of property", sort of, as said [in this comment](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1000#issuecomment-752029660):

> your properties are assumed to be equal from swagger-core library.
> In order to tell swagger the properties are not the same, you can add the Schema annotation on each property, so they can have different annotations

It means that if you have multiple `private String myField...` in a class, some won't be seen here.

It's a shame, because `PropertyCustomizer` is the only way I know where you can write the OpenApi schema while still accessing the Java class, its fields, methods and annotations.

---

Then, you could try to provide an `OpenApiCustomizer`: there, you have access to all the components schemas.

It means you'd have to find all classes with `@Nullable` fields by your own way, using reflections. But be careful, there are a lot of edge cases.

By example, you could use Spring `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` and `AssignableTypeFilter` to find all classes inheriting a precise class (like a parent `Dto` class), but then you will miss all abstract classes, unless you rewrite your own scanner.

Then, with a map of all the nullable fields, you could walk the `OpenApi.getComponents().getSchemas()`, and apply to `Schema.required()` all properties except the nullable ones. But then, when using inheritance, some properties are not directy in the schema but in the `allOf` part, which you'd have to handle.

That's where we stopped trying.

---

In summary, there are a lot of caveats, handling abstractness, inheritance, $refs, and so forth.

All of that made me think that this solution is kind of brittle, and that I could be missing other potential failure causes. At this point, in my opinion, it's not worth it.